# Blender Scripting, save segmentation mask

Tags: python, rendering, scripting, compositing-nodes

My script looks like this:

```
import bpy
import math
import random
import time
from mathutils import Euler, Color
from pathlib import Path

def randomly_rotate_object(obj_to_change):
    ##Applies a random rotation
    random_rot = (random.random() * 2 * math.pi, random.random() * 2 * math.pi, random.random() * 2 * math.pi)
    obj_to_change.rotation_euler = Euler(random_rot, 'XYZ')

out_path = 'D:/Blender/test_render'

for i in range(0,3):
    randomly_rotate_object(bpy.context.scene.objects[3])
    bpy.context.scene.render.filepath = out_path + "//" + "test_" + str(i) + ".png"
    bpy.ops.render.render(write_still=True)
```

I want to create a segmentation mask of the hand (pass index=255):
[image]

[image]

If I run the script, 3 images are generated , but the segmentation mask is overwritten in each step. How can I modify my script so that a mask is created for each image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set names via python like this:

```
slots = bpy.context.scene.node_tree.nodes['File Output'].file_slots
slots[0].path =  "image_" + str(i)  
slots[1].path =  "segmentation_" + str(i)
```

Comment: It works. Thank you!